# Set up secrets in Drone return empty value

Tags: drone.io

I'm trying to setup secrets in Drone but without any luck. A simple operation like adding a secret doesn't work for me. I've tried in several ways but no result.

I'm running Drone 0.5.

this is what I run:

`drone secret add --skip-verify=true org/my_repo PRIVATE_KEY @/Users/me/.ssh/my_key.pem`

the result is this:

```
[
    {
        "conceal": false,
        "event": [
            "push",
            "tag",
            "deployment"
        ],
        "id": 30,
        "name": "PRIVATE_KEY",
        "skip_verify": true,
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

By design Drone doesn't show secret in the JSON response